# Connection between Qt and Code in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed Qt on Visual Studio 2013 and i have a question: How can i make the connection between a button and my code from visual?. I need to make a simple menu for my aplication.

Comment: I say the easiest method would be to use the qtaddon. I use CMake to generate all of my Visual Studio projects however that comes with a learning curve..

Comment: Could u be a little more explicit? So, i have an aplication which generates different raports about cars. I need to make buttons for these raports.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I thought the problem was getting started developing Qt applications inside Visual Studio. Now it seems the question is completely different. Although we may have a language barrier.

Comment: No, it-s not duplicate. I have qt installed, i can make buttons, windows, but i don-t know to connect with my code

Comment: Maybe you should show a small example (source code) of what you are trying to accomplish. And where you have the problem.

Comment: So, i have installed Qt on Visual Studio 2013. After that, i have created a Qt project, then i pressed on extension.ui for opening Qt Creator from Visual Studio. There, I could make buttons, windows, but i don-t know how to put that buttons in connection with my code.

Comment: So you do not know how to create a c++ class for your .ui file? Or you do not know how to connect your button signals to other slots?

Comment: I think the button signals to other slots. For example, let-s take a file where i have information about a car, such us model, engine, consumption etc. I want to make a button, and when i press it, i want to display that file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like specifying connections in the UI file using the GUI (where you can select a signal and a slot and it will do the rest of the work for you). The GUI is buggy. I recommend calling the `connect` method yourself in your code. For example, in the main window constructor or a special method that sets up all the connections (and is, in turn, called by the constructor):

```
connect(ui->button, SIGNAL(clicked(void)), this /* or some other object */, SLOT(buttonClicked(void));
```

If you use Qt 5 and not Qt 4, I also recommend the new connection syntax. It's both easier to debug (you're likely to get a compile-time error instead of runtime error if the connection can't be made), and, I suspect, might result in slightly faster / smaller code:

```
connect(ui->button, &QPushButton::clicked, this /* or some other object */, &CMainWindow::buttonClicked);
```

The latter method also has the additional benefit of autocompletion working in Visual Studio and not only in Qt Creator.

Comment: @Sebi95: please clarify the question, I don't understand.

Comment: I-ve solved the problem. Thx for ur help. One more question: It's any posibility to read a file in Qt without indicating the path?

Comment: ***It's any posibility to read a file in Qt without indicating the path?*** To save users time its usually best to specify a path. Searching a file system can take a long time.

Comment: Yes, but i need to send this aplication to my teacher. He wants only to execute..